# Problems installing applications on ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, 18.04, system-installation

Every time I try to install something on my Ubuntu, the script stops and crashes in this step: `Building initial module for 5.3.0-42-generic`, and at the end it says:

```
  Errors were found while processing:  
  amdgpu-dkms  
  amdgpu-hwe  
  amdgpu-pro-hwe  
  amdgpu-pro-lib32
```

Which is part of the drivers that I tried to install for my video card?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you could load from previous working kernel and remove the newer 42-generic. Maybe your gpu drivers are not compatible with that new kernel.